# Kotlin: javaSetter method is not compiling

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection, compiler-errors, kotlin-reflect

I retrieved a property of my class using:

```
 val prop = businessObject::class.memberProperties.first()
```

I can do this:

```
prop.javaGetter
```

But this method does not compile:

```
prop.javaSetter
```

Even though the method exists and is not deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not compiling because [`memberProperties`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/member-properties.html) is a `Collection<KProperty1>`, and [`KProperty1`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/index.html) doesn't have any `javaSetter` property. But you can test if the property [is in fact a `KMutableProperty1`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-property1/index.html#inheritors), and if it is, after a cast or a smart cast, use its [`javaSetter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.jvm/java-setter.html) property.

As you can see, the documentation helps. Use it.